# Symfony2 how to get entity alias in repository

Tags: symfony

i would like to write some DQL query in my entity repository function but instead of haroding entity alias into DQL i would like to get actual entity alias from repository.
my repository:

```
/**
 * TrackingRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class TrackingRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function test()
    {
        $dql = 'SELECT * FROM MyBundle:Tracking';
        // i would like to call something like this:
        // $dql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->getEntityAlias;
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
        ...
    }
}
```

is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the entity class with `$this->getClassName()` in your repository :

```
class TrackingRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function test()
    {
        $dql = 'SELECT t FROM ' . $this->getClassName() . ' t';
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: well this generates:
"SELECT * FROM MyBundle\Entity\Tracking AS t"
and cause exception, i need:
"SELECT * FROM MyBundle:Tracking AS t"

Comment: ... I just try to resolve your problem :/ You can't use the "*" in DQL, you must use the alias instead, in this case it's "t".
By replacing * with t, the exception should no longer appear.

Comment: thanks for your effort, i didnt catch that your response was a follow up to this answer! it seems to resolve things

Answer (score 0):

What kind of query you want to execute? Are you realy need DQL? There are other ways to achive execute complex query, please consider:

Repository `findBy($criteria)`:

```
public function test()
{
    $this-> findBy($criteria);
}
```

For more complex queries you can also use:

Criteria and matching:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

//

public function test()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('sth', 'val'))
        // more criteria here

    $result = $this->matching($criteria);
}
```

Doctrine's [Query Builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#using-doctrine-s-query-builder)

Or even Query Builder with specific criteria [expressions](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.php):

```
public function test()
{
    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb
        ->where($qb->expr()->andx(
            $qb->expr()->in('p', '?1'),
            $qb->expr()->isNotNull('p.someField')
        ))
        ->setParameter(1, $someValue);

    $result = $this->matching($criteria);
}
```

Comment: findBy is not sufficient. i need to create complex query, thats why im using DQL. anyways this is no related to my question

Comment: @gondo I've updated my answer. Are you realy need DQL? Please consider my tips.

Comment: well my query looks like this if you can rewrite it to QueryBuilder an ll make it looks less complicated than DQL: `SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e, t.f FROM table t WHERE t.a = 0 AND t.b <> 2 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(COALESCE(t.c, 0)) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - t.d ORDER BY t.c ASC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
class TrackingRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   public function test()
   {
    $dql = 'SELECT t.property1,t.property2,t.property3,t.property4 FROM MyBundle:Tracking t';
    // i would like to call something like this:
    // $dql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->getEntityAlias;
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: how does this solve my problem in any way? you are still using harcoded alias MyBundle:Tracking in your query